# TSQL find missing Values for repeating records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Sample Data:

```
PageID  Attribute
2860    Category
2860    Sub-Category
2861    Tag
2861    Tag
2862    Tag
2862    Category
2863    Sub-Category
2883    Category
2883    Sub-Category
```

**Problem # 1:** I need to find the page ids where the attribute `Sub-Category` does not exists so my result should be :

```
2861
2862
```

**Problem # 2:** I need to find the page ids where the attribute `Sub-Category` and the attribute `Category` both do not exists so my result should be :

```
2861
```

Comment: Problem #1 expected output should not contains 2862 as it contains 'Sub-Category'

Comment: Corrected data Thanks

Comment: Your Second problem output should also be 2861
2862  same as first problem. because 2861  not have both but also 2862    only have 'Category'  but not 'Sub-Category'.

Comment: No problem # 2 is a AND condition, both do not have to exist which is why 2862 is not part of the result.

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
select pageid 
from thetable 
where pageid not in (select pageid from thetable where attribute = 'sub-category')
```

2)

```
select pageid 
from thetable 
where pageid not in (select pageid from thetable where attribute = 'sub-category')
and pageid not in (select pageid from thetable where attribute = 'category')
```

Comment: I think the second solution is incorrect because it will exclude records which have only sub-category or category since the and is not taking care of looking up both (category and subcategory) at the same time.

Comment: I did try it and it works - @MurtazaMandvi can you explain why you think the AND would act like an OR in this case?  Both have to be true in order for the select to return the pageid

Answer (score 1):

The SQL-as-plain-English solution:

**Problem # 1**: I need to find the page ids where the attribute Sub-Category does not exists.  In other words, *"all the page ids except the ones with an Attribute of 'Sub-Category'*

```
SELECT PageID FROM MyTable
EXCEPT
SELECT PageID FROM MyTable WHERE Attribute = 'Sub-Category'
```

**Problem # 2**: I need to find the page ids where the attribute Sub-Category and the attribute Category both do not exist. In other words, *"all the page ids except the ones with an Attribute of 'Sub-Category' or 'Category'"*

```
SELECT PageID FROM MyTable
EXCEPT
SELECT PageID FROM MyTable WHERE Attribute IN ('Category','Sub-Category')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**:

```
Select PageID From Table
Group By PageID
Having Sum(Case When Attribute = 'Sub-category' Then 1 Else 0 End) = 0
```

**Problem 2**:

```
Select PageID From Table
Group By PageID
Having Sum(Case When Attribute In('Category', 'Sub-category') Then 1 Else 0 End) = 0
```